# How do I calculate the Radius of convergence of this sum

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

What is the radius of convergence?

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} n^3 (5x+10)^n$$

Comment: Ratio Test looks good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your sum is a power series:

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} n^3 (5x+10)^n = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} n^3 5^n (x- (-2))^n$$

So the series is centered around the $x_0 = -2$, and its radius of convergence is

$$\frac{1}{\rho} = \overline{\lim_{n \to \infty}} \sqrt[n]{|a_n|}$$

(Cauchy Hadamard formula, where $\rho$ is the radius of convergence and the RHS is the supremum limit)

In your case, $$\frac{1}{\rho} = 5 \Rightarrow \rho = \frac{1}{5}$$

That is to say that the series converges $\forall x \in (-2 - \frac{1}{5}, -2 + \frac{1}{5})$

You should actually check what happens at the extreme of the interval but that was not required by the question I think :)

Comment: What is not correct?

Comment: Superb. Thanks alot. :-)))

Comment: @Ron you're welcome ;-) If you've liked the answer, please accept it (there is a little check under the vote count)

Answer (score 0):

We use the Ratio Test (the Root Test will also work nicely).The series obviously converges if $5x+10=0$.

When $5x+10\ne 0$, we find
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{(n+1)^3 |5x+10|^{n+1}}{n^3|5x+10|^n}.$$
Fairly quickly, we find that this limit is $|5x+10|$.

Thus our series converges if $|5x+10|\lt 1$, and diverges if $|5x+10|\gt 1$.

It follows that the series converges if $-\frac{11}{5}\lt x\lt -\frac{9}{5}$.

This is an interval of width $\frac{2}{5}$ centered around $x=-2$. The radius of convergence is therefore $\frac{1}{5}$.

For completeness (this is not needed) the series diverges at the endpoints $x=-\frac{11}{5}$ and $-\frac{9}{5}$.

Comment: FANTASTIC :-))) Thakns alot

Comment: You are welcome. After a while you can do these things more mechanically.